# hdfs spark-defaults.conf cleaner

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I added the following properties to `spark-defaults.conf` :

`spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled true`

`spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval 1d`

`spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge 7d`

1. Do I need to stop/start service for the new configuration to take effect?
2. If the interval is daily, how can I know when it is supposed to run?